# Calculating how many times multiples of numbers go into a number

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and a number, like so:

```
var offers = [{
    quantity_needed: 5,
    price: 1200
}, {
    quantity_needed: 8,
    price: 1400
}, {
    quantity_needed: 10,
    price: 1500
}];

var quantity = 9;
```

I want to calculate price groups from the offers, using the highest numbers possible.

So say I had **25**, that would mean I took **10** from the array twice and **5** once, creating **25**.

If I had **19**, that'd be **10** once, **8** once and **1** left over.

I managed to get so far with it, which would return the ones closest and I'd just get the highest result.

```
function discount(offers, quantity) {
    var found = [];
    offers.map(function (e) {
        found.push(Math.floor(quantity / e.quantity_needed) * e.quantity_needed);
    });
    return found;
}

discount(offers, 9) //Would return [5, 8, 0] 
discount(offers, 15) //Would return [15, 8, 10] which is wrong
```

I'm wanting it to return something like,

```
discount(offers, 16) //{10: 1, 8: 0, 5: 1, remainder: 1}
discount(offers, 25) //{10: 2, 8: 0, 5: 1, remainder: 0}
```

Comment: Are 10, 8 & 5 the only 3 price-groups that you're wanting to apply?

Comment: This algorithm is what you want (i.e. start with the highest denominator, then filling up with lower ones): http://kganser.com/change.html

Comment: @Matt No, these are dynamic values pulled from a database.

Comment: @BenFortune If your offers are dynamic, you need to make sure that a bigger package is always a better deal -- otherwise, the greedy algorithm won't work. The general case (there may be an offer with a small quantity that's a great deal) can be stated as an instance of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is NP-complete.

Comment: @Carsten The deal price isn't necessarily important, as the highest `quantity_needed` will always be the best deal. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help.

I ended up with the following:

```
var offers = [{
    quantity_needed: 5,
    price: 1200
}, {
    quantity_needed: 8,
    price: 2000
}, {
    quantity_needed: 10,
    price: 2400
}];

var quantity = 27;

function discount(offers, quantity) {
    offers.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.quantity_needed - a.quantity_needed;
    });
    var total = 0,
        result = {};
    offers.forEach(function (e) {
        result[e.quantity_needed] = 0;
        while ((total + e.quantity_needed) <= quantity) {
            result[e.quantity_needed]++;
            total += e.quantity_needed;
        }
    });
    result['remainder'] = quantity - total;
    return result;
}
```

Which returns

```
{5: 1, 8: 0, 10: 2, remainder: 2}
```

Comment: I guess you don't need to sort every time you call `discount` function. You can sort it once before calling `discount`.

Comment: @naota I have lots of objects which contain the offers array, sort will need to be called on each of them.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for. You can modify the code for your needs. The logic should remain same.

```
var quantity_needed={10,8,5}; // extract quatity needed into sorted int values
var quantity = 9;
var found={};

for(var i=0; i<quantity_needed.length; i++){

var temp=quantity_needed[i];

while(quantity>temp){
quantity=quantity-temp;
found.push(temp);
}


}
```

Here we subtract the largest quantity_needed possible from the quantity unless the quantity becomes less than the quantity_needed. Then we move to the next quantity needed. The only drawback to this approach is you have to have your array of quantity_needed sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/9pC4S/4/

```
function compare(a,b) {
    return b.quantity_needed - a.quantity_needed;
}

function discount(offers, quantity) {
    offers.sort(compare);
    var r = quantity;
    var found = [];
    offers.map(function (e) {
       var q = e.quantity_needed;
       var p = parseInt(r / q,10);
       found.push(q +":"+p);
       if(p>0){
           r -= q*p;  
       }
   });
   found.push("remainder:"+r);
   return found;
}


var a = discount(offers, 16);
a = discount(offers, 25);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution may interest you:

```
function discount(offers, quantity) {
    var found = {};
    var remainder;

    offers.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.quantity_needed - a.quantity_needed;
    });

    remainder = offers.reduce(function (prev, current) {
        var value = Math.floor(prev / current.quantity_needed);
        found[current.quantity_needed] = value;
        return prev - current.quantity_needed * value;
    }, quantity);

    found['remainder'] = remainder;

    return found;
}
```

Results:

```
discount(offers, 8); // => {5: 0, 8: 1, 10: 0, remainder: 0}
discount(offers, 16); // => {5: 1, 8: 0, 10: 1, remainder: 1}
discount(offers, 32); // => {5: 1, 8: 0, 10: 3, remainder: 2}
```